# How do I add/remove a CSS class in native AngularJS (not relying on jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to add/remove CSS classes just like jQuery's `$('#element').addClass('new_class')` and `removeClass()`. Does AngularJS offer a native solution that doesn't require jQuery or jQLite? Our main developer says he's going to remove jQuery for performance reasons, so I need a native solution.

I believe the example below uses jQLite, which would also be removed.

`angular.element('#element').addClass("new_class");`

Is there a truly native option?

P.S. I've used ngClass, and that doesn't seem to suit my need, since I need to control it from the Controller. I'm basically utilizing the Animate.css library for animations, thus on certain events I need to add/remove CSS classes to trigger the animation. I don't think I can achieve this with ngClass.

Comment: Did you consider googling "angular CSS class"? First hit: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: I've used ngClass before, but it doesn't suit my needs in this scenario. I need to trigger it from the Controller. I use Animate.css which is controlled by CSS classes, and on specific events I want to add/remove the classes to use these animations. The most elegant way is if there's an equivalent to jQuery's addClass() and removeClass()

Comment: So **mention that**, give a [mcve] that demonstrates the actual problem you're trying to solve (and how the solutions you've already tried failed to solve it).

Comment: read this article
https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass

Answer (score 0):

You just need to bind a variable into the directive "ng-class" and change it from the controller. Here is an example of how to do this:

```js
var app = angular.module("ap",[]);

app.controller("con",function($scope){
  $scope.class = "red";
  $scope.changeClass = function(){
    if ($scope.class === "red")
      $scope.class = "blue";
    else
      $scope.class = "red";
  };
});
```

```css
.red{
  color:red;
}

.blue{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="ap" ng-controller="con">
  <div ng-class="class">{{class}}</div>
  <button ng-click="changeClass()">Change Class</button>    
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This site will be a good resource in your move away from jQuery:
http://youmightnotneedjquery.com

This was the example to remove a class:

```
if (el.classList)
  el.classList.remove(className);
else
  el.className = el.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\b)' + className.split(' ').join('|') + '(\\b|$)', 'gi'), ' ');
```

That should be enough to get you going.